Parsing value to HTTP Request on Power Automate
Given an output like following,
[
{
"CompanyName": "CONTONSO"
},
{
"CompanyName": "M365"
},
....
]
I'm trying to loop through all the Companies running the Graph API Query with no luck.
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$filter=companyName eq @{item('Apply_to_each')} and accountEnabled eq true
The error im getting is:
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'HTTP' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'item' must not have any parameters.'.

URL works fine if Company Name is typed manually, but im not able to get it to work using the loop items. (Query requires header ConsistencyLevel with value Eventual)
Any help will be appreciated.

That can’t be the full expression, you’re missing a closing curly bracket. Also, you haven’t specified a property to pull through in the OData filter, you’re just referencing the entire object.

Edited query and error was gone. This is the final query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=accountEnabled eq true and companyName eq '@{item()['CompanyCode']}'

Thanks to Skin comment for pointing out
